# error on redirecting on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Font from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ServerIP' is therefore not allowed access.

How can I change the baseURL in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change WordPress base url from settings and also change base url from phpmyadmin options table as well.

Below is the link for more details and how to change the base url

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Change_WordPress_Site_URL